# Click event starts animation late

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make kind of a gallery, you click the thumbnail image and it opens that image just zoomed and then I append arrows next to image to be able to navigate, the problem is that when you click arrow for first time everything is good, but the more you click the later will start the action, for example if you click first time, it fades out image immediately if you click eight time the arrow it will fade out image only after 2 seconds.

```
arrows.on('click', function(){
  if(action === false){
  action = true;
  if($(this).hasClass("left")){
    if(parseInt(curr_img) - 1 > 0){
        curr_img--;
    }else{
        curr_img = 12;
    }
    $(".premii").fadeTo("fast", 0, function(){
        $(this).children("img").attr("src", path + curr_img + '.jpg');
        if(diploma['diploma_' + curr_img].pos === "ver"){
            if(!$(this).children("img").hasClass("ver")){
            $(this).children("img").addClass("ver");
        }
        }else{
            $(this).children("img").removeClass("ver");
        }
        $(this).children("img").load(function(){
            curr_height = $(".premii").height();
            $(".premii").fadeTo("fast", 1, function(){
                action = false;
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time `$(this).children("img").load` is executed, another Load-Eventhandler is attached to the images inside your div. But this growing stack of event handlers is executed each time you click the button.
So you have to change 
`.load(function()` 
to 
`.one("load", function()`
 This adds an one-time event handler to the images.
It is a clean approach, not just stopping the animation queue.